# DBMS_JOB.Broken in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-scheduler, dbms-job

Unable to find the replacement for DBMS_JOB.Broken command to make the job broken. Please assist me for the same.
Command used in my code is

```
dbms_job.broken(oracle_job_num, true);
```

Have done the changes for the below commands which was used in our code.

```
DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT -> DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
DBMS_JOB.REMOVE -> DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is a specific api to mark a job as broken in dbms_scheduler but there is one to enable it again:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(name=>'test_job');
```

There is an api to change after how many failures a job will be disabled:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute (name=>'test_job', attribute=>'max_failures',value=>3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DBMS_SCHEDULER.DISABLE('JOB_NAME')` and `DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE('JOBNAME')` instead of `DBMS_JOB.BROKEN(ORACLE_JOB_NUM, TRUE)` and `DBMS_JOB.BROKEN(ORACLE_JOB_NUM, FALSE)`. The "broken" and "enabled" functionality are not exactly the same, because [DBMS_JOBS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_JOB.html#GUID-8910BB81-3A94-4E51-8970-7ECCCD6F24BA) automatically breaks jobs after 16 failures, whereas [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html#GUID-89005DCD-B8CF-4CEE-B36C-2347BD3A81C6) does not. But if you're just using BROKEN to manually disable and enable, then the behavior should be close enough.